# Calling Thread.interrupt() for IntentService

Tags: android

I have some wait-notify code written inside an IntentService. I want to interrupt this service from outside, but I can't see a way to get reference of IntentService as a Thread, to call interrupt().

Comment: add some code and elaborate question what exactly you want to do and why you want to do like this ?

Comment: did you find out an answer for this?

Comment: @AlonBurg : No, I actually had no requirement to do it. Was preparing my code for a test scenario if the OS calls interrupt(), will it break my code.